# How to extract a date value from a string using regexp in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

`var value = "/Date(1454187600000+0300)/"` - from this i required a date format like `1/30/2016` - for this i am trying like this:

```
var value = "/Date(1454187600000+0300)/" // i need to fetch from here.
var nd = new Date(1454187600000); //this is static.
var month = nd.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
var day = nd.getUTCDate();
var year = nd.getUTCFullYear();
newdate = month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
console.log( newdate ); //works fine
```

But I don't know how to fetch the numbers from `value` variable using regexp. any one help me?

Comment: Do you want to access 1454187600000+0300 from /Date(1454187600000+0300)/"

Comment: if you want to extract that number then you don't need regex,
you can simply split the string "/Date(1454187600000+0300)/"
Example : 
"/Date(1454187600000+0300)/".split('+')[0],split('(')[1]

Comment: You've accepted an answer that completely disregards the `+0300` part of the string. Do you know that you can do that without getting a value that's three hours off? If so, that would be important information to include in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use capture group to extract the date part you're looking for:

```
nd = new Date(value.match(/\/Date\((\d+)/)[1] * 1);
//=> Sat Jan 30 2016 16:00:00 GMT-0500 (EST)
```

Here `/\/Date\((\d+)/)[1]` will give you `"1454187600000"` and `* 1` will convert that text into integer.

Comment: Well, for one thing it completely disregards the timezone offset, which is presumably significant information. E.g., the value would (presumably) be three hours off in the OP's example.

Comment: Umm I just answered on extracting that number from first string and rest is the code OP already has shown. Won't `getUTC` functions return values from UTC date

Comment: some times i am getting a value with '-' prepanded like : 'Date(-19800000-0300)' can you add a option to handle this

Comment: still i am getting issue, how to handle this value, value2 - here : https://jsfiddle.net/42kdmpr0/

Answer (score 0):

if you want to extract that number then you don't need regex, you can simply split the string "/Date(1454187600000+0300)/" 
Example : "/Date(1454187600000+0300)/".split('+')[0],split('(')[1]

Comment: it works, but some times, i will get instead of `+` even `-` too. how to add the options

Answer (score 0):

A pair of capture groups will give you the numbers (well, strings you can convert to numbers), but then you need to adjust the number to account for the timezone before passing it to `new Date`, which is easy with a couple more captures. See comments:

```js
var value = "/Date(1454187600000+0300)/";
// Get the parts
var parts = /^\/Date\((\d+)([-+])(\d{2})(\d{2})\)\/$/.exec(value);
// Get the time portion as a number (milliseconds since The Epoch)
var time = +parts[1];
// Get the offset in milliseconds
var offset = (+parts[3] * 3600 + +parts[4] * 60) * 1000;
// Apply the offset
if (parts[2] == "+") {
  // The timezone is `+` meaning it's *ahead* of UTC, so we
  // *subtract* the offset to get UTC
  time -= offset;
} else {
  // The timezone is `-` meaning it's *behind* UTC, so we
  // *add* the offset to get UTC
  time += offset;
}
// Get the date
var dt = new Date(time);
document.body.innerHTML = dt.toISOString();
```

The regex `/^\/Date\((\d+)([-+])(\d{2})(\d{2})\)\/$/` is:

- `^` - Start of input
- `\/` - A literal `/`
- `Date` - The literal text `Date`
- `\(` - A literal `(`
- `(\d+)` - A capture group for one or more digits; this is for the big number
- `([-+])` - A capture group for the sign of the offset, `-` or `+`
- `(\d{2})` - A capture group for exactly two digits; this is the hours portion of the offset
- `(\d{2})` - A capture group for another two digits; this is the minutes portion of the offset
- `\)` - A literal `)`
- `\/` - A literal `/`
- `$` - End of input

[Explanation on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pD1tI0/1)